Subtitles are always stuck in first line using ffmpeg fluent, same command works perfectly on cmd
im making a tool that generates assets, 3 image, 3 audios and 3 srt subtitles files.
Then doing a for loop to generate 3 separate videos putting those assets together.
the video is working fine when it comes to image and audio, but the subtitles are stuck on the first line.
I have tried outputOptions(vf -subtitlesFile), videoFilters(vf -subtitlesFile) input(subFile).
And nothing works, In each scenario the srt is stuck in first line like so.
When i do it on command like -i b-roll-2.png -i voiceover-2.mp3 -vf "subtitles=voiceover-2.srt" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest output22.mp4. It works perfectly.
The files are dynamic, but ffmpeg is reaching all of then.
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:03,900
To influence people, make one key change in how you talk,
(Stuck here)
2
00:00:03,900 --> 00:00:06,580
says communication expert Matt Abrahams.
this is my code, im using node.js
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    const inputImage = path.join(dir, images[i]);
    const inputAudio = path.join(dir, audio[i]);
    const inputSub = path.join(dir, sub[i]).replace(/\\/g, "/");
    const outputVideo = path.join(dir, `output_${i}.mp4`);

    if (!fs.existsSync(inputImage)) {
      console.error(`Image file not found: ${inputImage}`);
      continue;
    }
    if (!fs.existsSync(inputAudio)) {
      console.error(`Audio file not found: ${inputAudio}`);
      continue;
    }
    if (!fs.existsSync(inputSub)) {
      console.error(`Sub file not found: ${inputSub}`);
      continue;
    }

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ffmpeg()
        .input(inputImage)
        .input(inputAudio)
        .videoCodec("libx264") // Set video codec
        .audioCodec("copy") // Copy the audio without re-encoding
        .outputOptions([
          "-preset veryfast",
          "-pix_fmt yuv444p",
          `vf subtitles=${inputSub}`
        ])
        .on("stderr", (stderr) => {
          console.error("FFmpeg STDERR:", stderr); // Logs FFmpeg's standard error output
        })
        .on("stdout", (stdout) => {
          console.log("FFmpeg STDOUT:", stdout); // Logs FFmpeg's standard output
        })
        .on("end", resolve)
        .on("error", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
          console.error("Error: " + err.message);
          console.error("ffmpeg stdout: " + stdout);
          console.error("ffmpeg stderr: " + stderr);
          reject(err);
        })
        .save(outputVideo);
    });
    console.log("ready processing");
  }

Tried everything but nothing works using fluent. Only cmd
